# Error usando Isolates y Geolocator para obtener la posición GPS en un hilo secundario, diferente del principal, en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hilos, geolocalización

### Lo que quiero hacer:

Tengo una app la cual tiene un botón que al presionarlo, abre un "AlertDialog" con dos "TextButtons". Si se pulsa en "Enviar", debería obtener la posición GPS cada 5 segundos, de manera indefinida, por lo que necesito ejecutar esta parte del código en un hilo o isolate distinto del principal, para que no se bloquee la app.

A continuación, muestro el código que interviene en esta operación (he prescindido del "while" y de la temporización de 5 segundos, a modo de simplificación, porque igualmente falla con una única consulta del GPS):

```
// ignore_for_file: must_be_immutable, library_private_types_in_public_api, prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables, use_build_context_synchronously, unnecessary_this

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:developer';

import '../components/command_tab.dart';
import '../components/login_api.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

////////////////////////////////////////
Future<Position> determinePosition() async {
  LocationPermission permission;
  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      return Future.error('error');
    }
  }
  return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
}

Future<Position> sendGPS(String aux) async {
  Position position = await determinePosition();
  // alarm_gps(arguments.username, arguments.password, arguments.ip, arguments.port, position.latitude.toString(), position.longitude.toString());
  return position;
}
////////////////////////////////////////

class FlutterCamera extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color? color;
  final Color? iconColor;
  final Duration? animationDuration;
  FlutterCamera({Key? key, this.animationDuration = const Duration(seconds: 1), this.iconColor = Colors.white, this.color}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _FlutterCameraState createState() => _FlutterCameraState();
}

class _FlutterCameraState extends State<FlutterCamera> {
  bool _isTouchOn = true;
  bool _isFrontCamera = false;
  bool _isStreaming = false;

  final Box box1 = Hive.box("logindata");
  CommandTab commandTab = CommandTab();

  List<CameraDescription>? cameras;
  CameraController? controller;

  void onPressed() async {
    Position position = await compute<String, Position>(sendGPS, "");
    print("Esta es la latitud: ${position.latitude}");
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {···

  /// calls [availableCameras()] which returns a list<CameraDescription>.
  Future initCamera() async {···

  /// chooses the camera to use, where the front camera has index = 1, and the rear camera has index = 0
  void setCamera(int index) {···

  /// removes the camera controller from memory after use.
  @override
  void dispose() {···

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {···

  ///Video View
  Widget videoView(username, password, ip, port) {···

  showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    // set up the buttons
    Widget cancelButton = TextButton(
      child: const Text("Cancelar"),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        print("CANCELAR");
      },
    );
    Widget continueButton = TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        onPressed();
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        print("ENVIAR");
      },
      child: const Text("Enviar"),
    );
    // set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: const Text("Enviar Alarama?"),
      content: const Text("Desea enviar ALARMA?"),
      actions: [
        cancelButton,
        continueButton,
      ],
    );
    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }

  /// button to close the camera view
  Widget closeCameraWidget() {···

  /// button to toggle the flash
  Widget flashToggleWidget() {···

  /// button to switch between front and rear cameras
  Widget cameraSwitcherWidget() {···
    
}
```

### Error obtenido:

Al pulsar el botón enviar e intentar obeneter la posición GPS, el Debug Console me muestra lo siguiente:

```sh
I/flutter ( 1433): ENVIAR
E/flutter ( 1433): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: The BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.instance value is invalid until BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized is executed.
E/flutter ( 1433): #0      BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.instance
_background_isolate_binary_messenger_io.dart:27
E/flutter ( 1433): #1      _findBinaryMessenger
platform_channel.dart:135
E/flutter ( 1433): #2      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger
platform_channel.dart:269
E/flutter ( 1433): #3      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
platform_channel.dart:303
E/flutter ( 1433): #4      MethodChannel.invokeMethod
platform_channel.dart:483
E/flutter ( 1433): #5      MethodChannelGeolocator.getCurrentPosition
method_channel_geolocator.dart:116
E/flutter ( 1433): #6      Geolocator.getCurrentPosition
geolocator.dart:119
E/flutter ( 1433): #7      sendGPS
flutter_camera.dart:47
E/flutter ( 1433): #8      compute.<anonymous closure>
_isolates_io.dart:19
E/flutter ( 1433): #9      _RemoteRunner._run (dart:isolate:1021:47)
E/flutter ( 1433): #10     _RemoteRunner._remoteExecute (dart:isolate:1015:12)
E/flutter ( 1433): #11     _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:17)
E/flutter ( 1433): #12     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)
```

He hecho muchas pruebas y el fallo se establece en este punto:

```
Position position = await determinePosition();
```

Si sustituyo esta función por otra trivial (cálculo fibonacci, i.e.), no da error, y el funcionamiento es el esperado, realizando los cálculos en un isolate secundario.